# What was the first animal having fur?

Tags: mammals, skin, palaeontology

Did all early mammals have fur? Is it possible to trace the origins, how early animals with fur looked like and how it evolved?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_mammals#Hair_and_fur

Comment: @Thaina That's what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Czech version: http://www.memento.junweb.cz/clanky/spzo20.htm